# Upload image to wordpress and saving details in db

Tags: php, wordpress, automation

I want to upload an image to wordpress via a php script completely outside wordpress. I know what tables i have to insert data to. However I've noticed that if i pass through the normal way wordpress creates various sizes of the image and also save this in db. Is there a way to simulate the upload of the image using a script completely outside wordpress.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it would be something like this:

```
<?php
    header('Response: HTTP/1.1 200 OK');
    define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
    require('../../../../wp-load.php');

  $uploadedfile = $_FILES['image'];
  if($uploadedfile['size'] > 0){
        $upload_overrides = array( 'test_form' => false );
        if ( ! function_exists( 'wp_handle_upload' ) ) require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php' );
        $movefile = wp_handle_upload( $uploadedfile, $upload_overrides );
        if ($movefile) {
          $wp_filetype = $movefile['type'];
          $filename = $movefile['file'];
          $wp_upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
          $attachment = array(
            'guid' => $wp_upload_dir['url'] . '/' . basename( $filename ),
            'post_mime_type' => $wp_filetype,
            'post_title' => preg_replace('/\.[^.]+$/', '', basename($filename)),
            'post_content' => '',
            'post_status' => 'inherit'
          );
          $attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $filename);
      require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php' );
      $attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $filename );
      wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $attach_data );

          die(json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Ok', 'error' => 0)));
        }else{
            die(json_encode(array('type'=>'error',  'error' => 1)));
        }
  }
    die(json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'error' => 2)));
}
?>
```

Please note that i´ve pasted my code, you´ll have to work with it a little bit ;)